# How to convert date format to DD MMMM YYYY from Moment.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, momentjs

Getting Invalid date, if we try to format the date from moment.js.

**Code** `moment('18/01/2016').format("DD MMM YYYY"))`

Required Output : 18 jan 2016

but getting `invalid Date`.

Please Help

Comment: Btw `jan` is `MMM` format, not `MMMM` (which gives January)

Comment: ya thanks but its a typo mistake.

Comment: If you don't tell moment.js the input format, it guesses. Clearly it gets it wrong here (probably by assuming m/d/y).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is that [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) is not understanding the input format, so pass the input format to [`momentjs(string, string)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

```js
var string = moment('18/01/2016', 'DD/MM/YYYY').format("DD MMM YYYY")
result.innerHTML = string;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.2/moment.js"></script>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working perfectly..sorry for late reply.